# mkdir() is not working php

Tags: php, xampp, mkdir

At the end of my script, I call this:

```
if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
    mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
}
```

However it does not create the folder. The script that calls this statement is in the root dir of my project.

I am using XAMPP on Mac Yosemite if thats any help.

I have an error:

**PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/meeu/index.php on line 152**

line 152 being: **mkdir("user/$u", 0755);**

Edit:

I now have fixed the file path, however I var dump the mkdir and get this error:

**PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/meeu/index.php on line 152**

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file and tell us if you get any errors: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also check the permission of your directorys

Comment: @Rizier123 I added the php, however when I send the form which prompts the mkdir no errors are shown.

Comment: `mkdir` works fine. You did something wrong. Unfortunately we have no way of knowing what that something is. All your questions so far are "<language feature> doesn't work. Please help." Please read the SO FAQ for information on how to write a good question!!

Comment: @Josh Check the permission of the user dir if you are able to create other directorys  in it

Comment: @Rizier123 What do you mean ? How do I do that ?

Comment: @Josh This is not a problem with PHP, everything is performing as it should. The account that PHP is being run under does not have sufficient permission in the parent directory you are telling PHP to create a new directory under; so you need to fix the permissions. Also, whilst I understand you may need somewhere to ask these kind of questions, I don't think SO is really meant to be used as an introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at this. Your issue is most likely due to the fact that you're trying to `mkdir()` a relative path and not an absolute path.

You should try something like this:

```
if (!file_exists(getcwd() . "user/$u")) {
    mkdir(getcwd() . "user/$u", 0755);
}
```

---

References

- [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)
- Alternatively, you could use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) like this: `realpath(dirname(__FILE__));`

---

Also, as stated in the comments, turn on error reporting. (This is a must, every time you develop. Stop any issues before they arise).

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```